# How to remove all actions of a GtkEntryCompletion

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a GtkEntry which GtkEntryCompletion is completed with actions. Those actions are added dynamicaly with (ie their numbers and name can vary) with :

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html#gtk-entry-completion-insert-action-text

In the documentation, there is a function in order to remove an action based on its index. Since I don't keep tracks of the indexes and I don't want to, is there a way to remove all the actions in order to add new ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no another way than to save the number of actions I  add. I use it when I need to remove all the actions like this :

```
for (guint i = 0; i < num_actions; i++) {
  gtk_entry_completion_delete_action (entry_completion, 0);
}
```

The 0 value is the index. Since this index is relative, I just have to remove the action 0 n times.